# Open Project such file format on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a EE project and the project's format is file. I see other projects on NetBeans ---> openProject but its a different . its a file and it has src file , nb projects file. I cant see Netbeans ----> open Projects .    how can I that?  thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(No real answer but reformulated your question.)***

The directory containing a subdirectory `src` and possibly `.nb` (=NetBeans) form a NetBeans project. If there is a file `pom.xml` the project uses **maven** as build infrastructure.

Now you seem to have NetBeans project, but it is not recognized as such. You could try to install the newest NetBeans IDE. Or check for special characters in file names, inside of files. Maybe by copying the project on USB stick or so, file names got converted to capitals. **Maybe you still need to install the JavaEE plugin.** (Far fetched, unlikely all.)

Comment: thanks for your answer . I need to install EE plugin. I already new at EE part.